# OverWritting not working in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am running the following VBS program, with file name `check.vbs`

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://philiphacker.16mb.com/check.txt", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
.type = 1 '//binary
.open
.write xHttp.responseBody
.savetofile "d:\temp\check.txt", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

I get this program from internet, it works fine on downloading the file `check.txt` but when i download it again in the same location , it is not overwitting the file `check.txt`

at first my `check.txt` file contains "0"
at second time when i download `check.txt` file contains "1"

but, its not overwritting, `check.txt` still contains "0" 
but, the `check.txt` file in the url value has changed to "1"

i hope i tried my best to make understand the question..
Please help me guys..

Comment: Your code above downloads a file called check.txt and it only contains numeric value `D67` (for me). Same behavior in overwriting. Where's a zero???

Comment: The same remark as @GTAVLover we have the same result ! i got D67 and the overwritten works great ! so where is your issue ?

Comment: @Hackoo it seems that OP has given a sample site in his post :-| however overwriting works fine.